# reshape to wide format when more than two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Apologize if this question has been asked before, i didn't find nothing similar.
So, it's trivial to reshape when we have something like

```
id status1 value
1  active   1
2  close    23
```

result after reshaping will be

```
id active close
1  1      23
```

but, what if our table have more than one status column? and we need to reshape by status1, and status2 columns?

```
id status1 status2 value
1  active  complete 2
2  close   overdue  3
```

Expecting result

```
id active close complete overdue
```

Home the question is clear.
Any comments or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with the data you want to reshape and you don't know how. Showing an example of an already solved problem doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're after, but maybe this could work.

example:

```
library(reshape2)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3), c("Active", "Close", "Active"),c("one", "two", "one"), c(5,6,7)))
colnames(df) <- c("id", "status1", "status2", "value")

df1 <- dcast(df, id ~ status1)
df2 <- dcast(df, id ~ status2)

merge(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- read.table(header=T, text="id status1 status2 val
1  active  complete 2
2  close   overdue  3")
recast(df, id~value, id.var = c(1, 4), value.var = "val")
#   id active close complete overdue
# 1  1      2    NA        2      NA
# 2  2     NA     3       NA       3
```